# Is there a npm package, or web api, for reading specific parts of an image?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, parsing, artificial-intelligence

I'm adding a new function to my node express server that will allow me to upload a drivers ELD daily log and get from that image / pdf the time driven, start time, end time, lunch, etc..

[image: Demo Log]

I've looking into converting the pdf into a csv / json / html, but the issue there is that it's an unlabeled mess. So I am figuring that trying to somehow read and create a chart similar to the chart already on the eld log.

ie. Reading it would be segmented by say 15 minutes, or however many pixels.

[image: Area of focus]

`IF line exists in segment call proceed and log data ELSE check segments "SB" "D" "ON" then recursively call`

[image: Semented area of focus]

In the example shown above, this driver went on duty at 6:45am.

The files are provided in a pdf format, and I am having issues extracting the data and have it be useful / labeled.

UPDATE: Thinking about it a bit more, this solution might be pretty resource costly, especially if done on the server end, ie. chopping up the image / leaving it in a buffer and reading off it... Maybe it would be better to just try and make sense of the garbage parsing from pdf to something else...

UPDATE 2: I may try and use [Tesseractocr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tesseractocr) depending on how it outputs data.

Using on a page like this:

[image: Demo Page 2 ELD Log]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the term you're looking for is OCR (optical character recognition). That's the name of the technology for converting text on images into actual text to work with. Once you have that, decoding the text should be easy if it's in a standard format. There are plenty of OCR libraries for Node: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=OCR No need to reinvent the wheel and try to build your own OCR system :)

Comment: :O Taking a look now. I appreciate the response!

Comment: So, that would put me at a new issue. Working with, reworking an, ocr package to fit the solution I'm working on, as far as I can tell, wouldn't allow me to read from the ELD graph but instead of text that exists on the page.

I feel that recreating the ELD graph would provide a much simpler approach to getting the data needed to complete the recon program.

Depending on how this package outputs data, I may try and move forward with https://www.npmjs.com/package/tesseractocr ..

Comment: I've got to say, recognizing a graph and extracting data from it via an image is almost certainly not going to be easier than reading the text. If the data you want is only in the graph and not obtainable from the text, then you're pretty screwed: you would, in fact, need to make your own image recognition system for it, and that is nowhere near an easy task.

Comment: Yeah, I started to realize that it was going to be difficult to analyze the eld graph the more I looked into this. With an OCR, I can just delimit and analyze the data from there.

Still, it's curious that image reading / visualizing is so difficult considering how many easy of life options there are out there. (I'm new to the whole software developer thing!)

Comment: Image processing is one of the harder fields of computer science that exists :) Humans find it easy to interpret visual information, but computers generally don't.